# Loop code with different worksheet names

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I am running below code. The worksheet named "fast" contains names such as cycle, run, walk, jog, etc. The code currently searches for the word "cycle" in a particular row and if found it copies the whole column and pastes it in a worksheet called "cycle". At the moment I am just repeating the script and changing "Cycle" for names like "run" "walk" etc. Is there I can make this shorter and more efficient by not simply just repeating the same script over and over.

```
Sub Cycle()

Dim C As Range
Dim col As Long, lastCol As Long

With Worksheets("fast")
    lastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    col = 1
    For Each C In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lastCol))
        If C.value = "Cycle" Then
            C.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cycle").Columns(col)
            C.EntireColumn.Copy
            Sheets("Cycle").Columns(col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            col = col + 1
        End If
    Next C
End With
Worksheets("Cycle").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you copy-paste twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, let me know if that's what you meant:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Cycle()

Dim C               As Range
Dim StringsArr      As Variant
Dim col As Long, lastCol As Long

StringsArr = Array("cycle", "run", "walk", "jog")

With Worksheets("fast")
    lastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For Each C In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lastCol))
        ' check per cell if value is one of the values in StringsArr array
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(C.value, StringsArr, 0)) Then
            col = Sheets(C.value).Cells(2, Sheets(C.value).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 ' find first empty column in relevant sheet
            C.EntireColumn.Copy
            Sheets(C.value).Columns(col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next C
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you left one hard-coded "Cycle"? `C.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cycle").Columns(col)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett just forgot to modify it , thanks :) , actualy not sure it's needed, cause he is doing `PasteSpecial` again later, waiting for PO feedback

Comment: Hi Both thanks for the response. The copy-paste twice was left over from code which I forgot to tidy up. The code works except the location where it pastes the column within the new worksheet is in random column rather than from A1 onwards,

Comment: @ShaiRado Perfect thank you very much Shai you are very helpful. Helps me learn new methods as well. Much appreciated.